# saving many to many relationship in EF 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity

I have problem with saving many to many relationship.
When I run the code, my mapping table "dbo.UserTown" does not have any data saved in this any idea why?

I have wrote my function for saving the users with lists of towns

```
  public void Save(User user)
    {
        context.User.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My classes are like this:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public String Nickname { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Residents")]
    public virtual ICollection<Town> Residencies { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Town
{
    public long TownId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Residents { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stange but i have discovered next day:
I have done steps to clear problem:

1. Fresh mug of coffe :)
2. cleared all cashe in vs (clear all projects), Closed Visual Studio for sure
3. Removed database
4. Open VS and run project => this step created database
5. Important: did NOT changed my code
6. Run the project 2nd time to seed dummy data into system
7. My table is populated.

Real headscratcher...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mapping class

```
public class User
{
  public long UserId { get; set; }
  public String Nickname { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<TownResidents> TownResidents { get; set; }
}

public class Town
{
  public long TownId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<TownResidents> TownResidents { get; set; }
}

public class TownResidents
{
  public long TownId { get; set; }
  public long UserId { get; set; }

  public virtual Town { get; set; } 
  public virtual User { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that i do, as ef generate mapping table for me and i do not want to create new object and new table as EF allready does this for me.

Comment: This is the right way, you can also check the question similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690467/entityframework-mutli-table-many-to-many/10690570#10690570

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create new entity to handle many to many relationships.
First of all remove `[InverseProperty("Residents")]` . It's redundant. Your model is fine without it.

`[InverseProperty("Entity")]` is required if You are having more than one 'to many' relationships between Your entities.

I guess Your problem lays is how you are adding related data into entities. I think this [article](http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-5/) will help You out.